# Blockchain is showing 2 incoming addresses for a transaction?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info

A transaction into one of my wallets is showing that it came from two addresses? How can I find out which one it came from?

Answer (score 4):

It came from both.

Transactions can have multiple senders and multiple recipients.

Sometimes a single address can also be *both* a sender and a recipient.

Comment: But what if I want to send money back to the person that sent it to me - what address do I use?

Comment: @sprstr you don't: you should contact him to ask him an address.